# Flutter Web Unsupported operation sort

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I'm trying to migrate my app to web and the sort method says it doesn't support it, any alternative?
My code:

```
      newRanking.sort((a, b) => b.general.compareTo(a.general));
```

I try sort a list but in web fail

Comment: Can you include sample but full snippet that will reproduce the issue(newRanking)

Comment: for (var element in body) {
        var rankingData = RankingData.fromJSON(element);
        newRanking.add(rankingData);
      }
      newRanking.sort((a, b) => b.general.compareTo(a.general));
      return newRanking;

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but didn't find the reason. I just added `toList` before `sort`, then it was working.

```
newRanking.toList().sort((a, b) => b.general.compareTo(a.general));
```